# Issue Deploying COM Components with ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, build, clickonce, publish

I'd like to publish an application developed in Visual Basic.Net 2010 which is dependent on a Com Component using ClickOnce.I've set the Isolated property of the Com object(dll kind of file) to True and the application builds successfully.However,dozens of nasty warnings pop up in Visual Studio Output window at the build saying:

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2580,9): warning MSB3179: Problem isolating COM reference 'AXmsCtrl': Registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{30f256c0-ee6e-4c57-a475-e3e81236119f}\Implemented Categories{7DD95801-9882-11CF-9FA9-00AA006C42C4}' was not imported".

Once the application is installed on a target machine on which the Com component isn't registered,It crashes to death.But,If you register the required Com object manually using the Regsvr32 Command,It'll be working like a charm.

To solve this problem,I've tried to change the target CPU in the Advance Compiler Settings to x86 from AnyCPU but that didn't work.Also,changed the target framework to .Net4 but that did nothing either.

I've gone my way out searching the web for an answer but all to no avail.I wonder if anyone could give me an insight to get this fixed.I'd appreciate it all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've used reg free COM in the past to deliver COM componets using ClickOnce. See [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.You see,I know how to publish Com components using Clickonce which is to set the Isolated property of them to True but the question is why I'm getting the warnings in the Output window?

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question at MSDN and one answer I found pretty useful was as follows:

> MSB3179: Problem isolating COM reference "assembly" : "error".
>   This is a generic error message indicating a problem with the generation of RegFree COM >entries in application manifest (as specified by the
>   IsolatedComReferences
>   task parameter). The latter part of the error message contains more information about the >nature of the problem. A possible cause of this error is that RegFree COM components are >not properly registered on the build computer.

To follow this question further and see the answers given at the MSDN community,[Click Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/30b1a8d1-51a9-486a-b6bf-43fc7cf2c469/#291b2865-5f56-40e4-b2b6-d8f3303f12e2)